# dependencyManagement in parent module pom.xml do not work

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I create a project with two modules, **ceo** ( parent module ) and **util**.
Why the IntelliJ IDEA show error messages like that `Cannot resolve symbol 'ObjectMapper'` in the module **util**.
- **util/src/main/java/localhost/util/Global.java**

```
package localhost.util;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Global {
    public final static ObjectMapper Jackson = new ObjectMapper();
}
//this class show error messages `Cannot resolve symbol 'ObjectMapper'`
```

[image]

- **ceo/pom.xml**, parent module

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>localhost</groupId>
    <artifactId>ceo</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>../util</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**util/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>ceo</artifactId>
        <groupId>localhost</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../ceo/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>util</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try this, <relativePath>../</relativePath> in your parent pom.xml

Comment: have add it `<parent>
        <artifactId>ceo</artifactId>
        <groupId>localhost</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../ceo/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>`

Comment: Try to replace ; <relativePath>../ceo/pom.xml</relativePath> => <relativePath>../</relativePath>